# Drupal: how can I read ip addresses of the people who is visiting my Drupal website?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Is there a way to read the ip address of the people who is currently visiting my Drupal website ?

Also, can I see the connections in real-time ? Is there any Drupal module for it ?

I need kinda a dinamyc list of ips

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring statistics
In Drupal 7 configure statistics via configuration > statistics.
In Drupal 6 configure statistics via administer > reports > access log settings.
In Drupal 5 configure statistics via administer > logs > access log settings.

To enable collection of statistics, the Enable access log checkbox on the Statistics settings page must be checked. This access log is used to store data about every page accessed, such as the remote host's IP address, where they came from (referrer), what node they've viewed, and their user name. Enabling the log adds one database call per page displayed by Drupal.

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing your own code, you can use PHP's normal $_SERVER array to pick up the visitor's IP address of any given page view.

If you're looking for pluggable Drupal modules, these ones ought to give you a good start:

- http://drupal.org/project/visitorinfo
- http://drupal.org/project/visitors

The other option is to install something like Google Analytics on your site. No Drupal module required; just sign up to Google Analytics and add the code to your site tempate.